# API8 to 7 compatibility

Tags: android, compatibility, android-2.0-eclair

What is the best way to make my app originally designed for API8 to be compatible with 7? I've noticed that AlertDialog features seem to cause trouble, for instance `showDialog()` doesn't work.

Comment: ... there is only `showDialog(int id)` version on API < 8 so if you don't using args from  `showDialog (int id, Bundle args)` you can use older version .... or as it's stated in doc you can use DialogFragment from compat library

Answer (score 2):

In your manifest file you can target 8 and require 7.  This will allow the app to run on 7 and show up in the market.  But obviously you need to test the dickens out of the app on 7 to make sure it runs well.  A good blog post on it is here
http://devtcg.blogspot.com/2009/12/gracefully-supporting-multiple-android.html

Another option that I don't think is good because you will have to support two or more code bases is to the use the multipal apk file support of the market.
http://developer.android.com/guide/market/publishing/multiple-apks.html